# How to crop image to show only the center portion?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am on Bootstrap 3. How do I show an image cropped in a `.col-sm-6` grid column?

The image is 720px wide.

On its own, with `.img-responsive`, when the display size changes, the image will be resized proportionally. I would instead like the left/right sides to be cropped off to show just a center portion, say 50%, of the image's original width.

Comment: https://twitter.com/ChallengesCss/status/1494274412304125956

Answer (score 0):

Although I have a hard time understanding why you are in BS3.
This is what we have:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position
CSS documentation. about image positioning

Development tools (chrome is fine).
Select the column, row, or image where you want to center the crop.
Then try the CSS properties to achieve what you want. [Chck example](https://youtu.be/CR0sr5iGqWo)

Another option is to use B.Strp Last. Probably more than you want.